# TOC formatting issue when headline close to numbering

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop, dita

I've run into a scenario where if the TOC title is too close to the TOC numbering, it pulls the numbering inwards.

Here you can see several examples where I started adding/removing one character at a time to see when it would incorrectly pull the numbering inward vs correctly wrapping to the next line.

[image: Incorrect TOC formatting]

Here are two blocks from topic.fo. The first is one is not pulling in the TOC numbering and the second is pulling the numbering in.

```
<fo:block
    start-indent="0in + (2 * 30pt) + 14pt">
    <fo:block
        end-indent="22pt"
        font-size="10pt"
        font-style="italic"
        font-weight="normal"
        last-line-end-indent="-22pt"
        text-align="justify"
        text-align-last="justify"
        text-indent="-14pt"
        line-height-shift-adjustment="disregard-shifts"
        font-family="Helvetica, Arial Unicode MS">
        <fo:basic-link
            internal-destination="_OPENTOPIC_TOC_PROCESSING_d73e797"
            line-height="150%"
            line-height-shift-adjustment="disregard-shifts"
            font-family="Helvetica, Arial Unicode MS">
            <fo:inline
                end-indent="14pt"
                keep-together.within-line="auto"
                line-height-shift-adjustment="disregard-shifts"
                font-family="Helvetica, Arial Unicode MS">Notes Associated with an Improperly Filled Card or a Negative Profile (Biopattern)</fo:inline>
            <fo:leader
                leader-pattern="dots"/>
            <fo:inline
                keep-together.within-line="always"
                padding-left.length="12pt"
                start-indent="-14pt"
                text-align="right"
                line-height-shift-adjustment="disregard-shifts"
                font-family="Helvetica, Arial Unicode MS">2-<fo:page-number-citation
                    ref-id="_OPENTOPIC_TOC_PROCESSING_d73e797"/>
            </fo:inline>
        </fo:basic-link>
    </fo:block>
</fo:block>
<fo:block
    start-indent="0in + (2 * 30pt) + 14pt">
    <fo:block
        end-indent="22pt"
        font-size="10pt"
        font-style="italic"
        font-weight="normal"
        last-line-end-indent="-22pt"
        text-align="justify"
        text-align-last="justify"
        text-indent="-14pt"
        line-height-shift-adjustment="disregard-shifts"
        font-family="Helvetica, Arial Unicode MS">
        <fo:basic-link
            internal-destination="_OPENTOPIC_TOC_PROCESSING_d73e800"
            line-height="150%"
            line-height-shift-adjustment="disregard-shifts"
            font-family="Helvetica, Arial Unicode MS">
            <fo:inline
                end-indent="14pt"
                keep-together.within-line="auto"
                line-height-shift-adjustment="disregard-shifts"
                font-family="Helvetica, Arial Unicode MS">Notes Associated with an Improperly Filled Card or with a Negative Profile (Biopat</fo:inline>
            <fo:leader
                leader-pattern="dots"/>
            <fo:inline
                keep-together.within-line="always"
                padding-left.length="12pt"
                start-indent="-14pt"
                text-align="right"
                line-height-shift-adjustment="disregard-shifts"
                font-family="Helvetica, Arial Unicode MS">2-<fo:page-number-citation
                    ref-id="_OPENTOPIC_TOC_PROCESSING_d73e800"/>
            </fo:inline>
        </fo:basic-link>
    </fo:block>
```

I've tried adjusting the different end-indents to see if I could force it to wrap without any luck. I am using DITA-OT 1.5.4 and FOP 1.0.

Comment: Looks like a bug in FOP in the way it reserves space for page number citation value and how that works with leader. Have you tried the same  in FO where you hard-code the page number 2-1 for those lines where page number is intended. If the hard-coded 2-1 doesn't create the indent, then it's a bug with page number citation and leader combo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look like a bug in FOP, see [FAQ](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/faq.html#page-number-align).

> This happens for fo:page-number-citation elements if the citation
>   occurs before FOP formatted the requested page, usually in TOC or
>   index pages. It is caused by the problem that FOP has to guess how
>   much space the yet unknown page number will occupy, and usually the
>   guesses are somewhat off.
>
> The most recent FOP releases should have this problem fixed. Check whether you can upgrade.